# Kotlin DSL migration project gradle build

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle-kotlin-dsl, kotlin-dsl

I am migrating to kotlin DSL

And this is my project level build gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.2.2' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.2.2' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.7.10' apply false
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I updated the file extension to -`build.gradle.kts`

And the file content to

```
plugins {
id ("com.android.application" version "7.2.2" apply false)
id ("com.android.library" version "7.2.2" apply false)
id ("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "${Versions.kotlin}" apply false)
}

tasks.register("clean",Delete::class){
    delete(rootProject.buildDir)
}
```

I am getting this error

```
Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch: 
public infix fun PluginDependencySpec.version(version: String?): PluginDependencySpec defined in org.gradle.kotlin.dsl
public infix fun PluginDependencySpec.version(version: Provider<String>): PluginDependencySpec defined in org.gradle.kotlin.dsl
```

Comment: The closing brace needs to go before `version` and `apply`: `id ("com.android.application") version "7.2.2" apply false`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update the plugins block as follows:

```kotlin
plugins {
    id ("com.android.application") version "7.2.2" apply false
    id ("com.android.library") version "7.2.2" apply false
    id ("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android") version "${Versions.kotlin}" apply false
}
```

Also, I think the `clean` task is available by default. You do not need to create it manually.

You can also consider migrating to Version Catalog while you are migrating. Please follow the [NowInAndroid](https://github.com/android/nowinandroid) app source code for that.